# DRY code in Angular2 templates?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I like the way you can easily bind properties, events etc. in angular2. You can put UI relevant code in your html and keep the component class pretty clean.

I have a snippet from a template i got, where i have a button to add the value of an input element, then clear the input field (to allow new input) and reset the focus in the element so you don't have to tab around a lot:

```
<div><input #newPlayer type="text">
<button type="button" 
(click)="addPlayer(newPlayer.value);newPlayer.value='';newPlayer.focus();">
ADD</button></div>
```

My component code is something like this:

```
public addPlayer(name: string) {
    if (!name.length) { return; };

    this.Players.push({ name: name});
}
```

This works great. The thing is, i figured that hitting the enter key in the input field should also behave like pressing the ADD button so my new html template looks like this:

```
<div><input #newPlayer type="text" 
(keyup.enter)="addPlayer(newPlayer.value);newPlayer.value='';newPlayer.focus();">
<button type="button" 
(click)="addPlayer(newPlayer.value);newPlayer.value='';newPlayer.focus();">
ADD</button></div>
```

Having to type the same list of commands for the extra event seems overkill, so i figured - what is the best pattern here? I was contemplating something like this:

```
<div><input #newPlayer type="text" 
(keyup.enter)="addPlayer(newPlayer)">
<button type="button" 
(click)="addPlayer(newPlayer)">
ADD</button></div>
```

Then change my component code to something like this:

```
public addPlayer(element: any) { // ElementRef?
    if (!element.value?.length) { return; };

    this.Players.push({ name: element.value});
    element.value = '';
    element.focus();
}
```

I'm not sure if this would even work, perhaps i need a reference to `Renderer` as well as `ElementRef` and this would confirm my suspicion that I'm not supposed to do this.

What would the best practice be?

Comment: Works as intended: http://plnkr.co/edit/sPcJLieYB10qHFQvZo7L?p=preview - only thing not working for me is the elvis operator you're using on `element.value?.length`

Comment: @rinukkusu yeah... i was thinking if it's the right way to go though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont understand your question clearly. But look at below code, this might help you.

```
 import {ElementRef,ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

 <input type="text" #newPlayer (keyup.enter)="addPlayer(newPlayer.value)" ... >
```

In component,

```
export class App{

    @ViewChild('newPlayer') input:ElementRef;

     addPlayer(){

       ...

     this.input.nativeElement.value=' ';
     this.input.nativeElement.focus();

     }

  }
```

Comment: Why might it help them?

Comment: In combination with your input @drewmoore it actually helps in seeing the different methods. I hadn't thought of using ViewChild in combination with sending only the value.

Comment: He doesnt know how to use `ElementRef` to hold `input control` with his written code. My code might help him. I have shown him a way to deal with ElementRef.

Comment: Fair enough, but please note this in your answer @micronyks. Otherwise it feels like your just stabbing in the dark :-)

Comment: @drewmoore ... Look at my first line of the answer. I have cleary written that i dont understand his question completely .

Comment: I actually did mention ElementRef and i've used it before - I like the input though. In my case i only got *one* input, so adding it as a ViewChild could work.

Comment: @Per even if you have more inputs, it can still work but then you have to opt for other available ways in angular2.

Comment: @micronyks that's what makes it feel like you're stabbing in the dark. If you truly don't understand a question, you shouldn't answer it.

Comment: @micronyks yep,, but if i had a collection instead, i think passing a reference to the right one (in the addPlayer call) would be smarter than trying to figure out which one i had to work on. But great input, thanks :)

Comment: It actually helped  him @drewmore. You can see it. Isnt it?

Comment: Not trying to add fuel to the fire, but i agree that you might want to ask questions if you don't think the question is clear, before posting an answer - you got it right first try this time though ;)

Comment: @Per Thats because I could figure out your problem area. But technically what you want is not clear to me. So just helped with code part. Look at the answer I have not given any kind of explanation to my answer rather I just showed you with what you can do with code.

Comment: @micronyks yes, your answer helped the OP, and it's a valuable answer if one reads through this comment thread - **but they shouldn't have to** - rather than saying "maybe this will help", your answer should take the form of "It looks like you're not understanding ___, so this might help..."

Comment: Agreed @drewmoore.